# Syntax of integer casting in C#

Tags: c#

In C, I would expect all three statements to be identical.

1. Single line (or, too concise for my own good?):

   ```
   // Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ushort'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
   return (UInt16)(r[1] << 8) | (UInt16)(r[0]);
   ```
2. The unacceptable triplet:

   ```
   // Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ushort'. An explicit conversion exists 
   UInt16 ret = r[0];
   ret = ret | (UInt16)(r[1] << 8);
   return ret;
   ```
3. The acceptable triplet:

   ```
   UInt16 ret = r[0];
   ret |= (UInt16)(r[1] << 8);
   return ret;
   ```

What casting did I miss?

For reference, the complete function:

```
public UInt16 read_word(byte addr, byte cmd, string descr = "")
{
    byte[] w = { cmd };
    byte[] r = read_write(addr, w, 2);
    // I can't figure out why the compiler rejects this statement:
    // return (UInt16)(r[1] << 8) | (UInt16)(r[0]);
    UInt16 ret = r[0];
    // The compiler also rejects this:
    // ret = ret | (UInt16)(r[1] << 8);
    // But, the compiler accepts this:
    ret |= (UInt16)(r[1] << 8);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can you show the abstract syntax trees? Usually each source code statement is also reflected as a separate node in an AST, so I would assume that your examples would differ in their AST representations. They could become the same ASTs through optimization steps.

Comment: Sorry I'll remove the distracting reference to AST.

Comment: You could compile all three approaches and then use ILDASM or something similar to view the emitted IL code.  That could give you an idea of whether or not one method performs significantly better than the rest.

Answer (score 2):

It's described in c# spec:

> **4.1.5 Integral types**
>
> - For the binary `+`, `–`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&`, `^`, `|`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` operators, the operands are converted to type `T`, where `T` is the first of `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong` that can fully represent all possible values of both operands. The operation is then performed using the precision of type `T`, and the type of the result is `T` (or `bool` for the relational operators). It is not permitted for one operand to be of type `long` and the other to be of type `ulong` with the binary operators.
> - For the binary `<<` and `>>` operators, the left operand is converted to type `T`, where `T` is the first of `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong` that can fully represent all possible values of the operand. The operation is then performed using the precision of type `T`, and the type of the result is `T`.

So when you're trying to perform `<<` on `UInt16` it's first transformed into `int` as that's the first one which can fully represent all possible values of `UInt16`. And returned value is `int` as well. That's why you have to cast the result to `UInt16` again.

Comment: I understand that `<<` transforms the expression to type `int`. However, the compiler still rejects the code with an *explicit cast* to `UInt16`, spelled `(UInt16)(r[1] << 8)`. I cannot imagine that expression has type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, using the bitwise operators on byte or short cause an implicit conversion to int.

I think the following should work:

```
return (UInt16)(r[1] << 8 | r[0]);

ret = (UInt16)(ret | (r[1] << 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the `|` operator isn't defined for `Uint16`.  ([MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) that it is only defined for the integral types, and `Uint16` [is a structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))  So I believe you are getting type promotion on this line:

```
ret |= (UInt16)(r[1] << 8);
```

to `int`, and then again (back to `UInt16` from `int`) when you return it:

```
return ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

in C# you could just do

```
UInt16 ret = (UInt16)(r[0] * 256 + r[1]);
```

Comment: Any decent optimizing compiler will reduce the `* 256` to `<< 8`. Why should I have to write one particular form of an isomorphism?

Comment: the point is you don't need to use bit wise operators multiplication and addition work on most types without changing them

Answer (score 0):

To break it down, you have:

```
return (UInt16)(r[1] << 8) | (UInt16)(r[0]);
```

This largely decomposes into:

```
int t1 = r[1] << 8; // -> r[1] << 8 results in implicit conversion to int
uint16 t2 = r[0];   // not much to see here
int t3 = t1 | t2 // // you're probably attempting to truncate to uint16 from int, which is not implicitly allowed.
return t3;
```

Basically, the compiler is telling you that it won't implicitly do the conversions you'd automatically expect from C. As annoying as it can be at times, it is doing it *for your safety* and eliminating the bane of C/C++: undefined behavior.  (I'm also guessing your eventual return type is a uint16?)

Comment: I should also note: in C/C++ when you do *any* bitwise operations (and/or/xor/not, etc) on anything *smaller* than an int, the operands are automatically promoted to an int.